# Adapting DDD interfaces to a concrete implementation

Tags: php, symfony, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, adapter

I'm currently trying to understand how to develop DDD classes, without any assumptions on the implementations that may need to use them. I managed to develop a small structure, made of a user object called `User` which implements a `IUser` interface so I can keep an efficient abstraction for reuse purposes.

I now would like to use this user object in a concrete implementation, by using Symfony2 in my case. In order to benefit from the Symfony security layer, my user object needs to implement the `UserInterface` interface provided by Symfony.

If I understand the pattern correctly, this would be a great opportunity to implement an Adapter called `UserAdapter` which would allow me to make my user class work with Symfony. So far so good, this works perfectly fine. But here goes my problem :

Suppose I add a `Comment` class in my DDD lib, which has an `$user` attribute. To bind a user to a comment, I use for instance a `setUser()` setter which requires anything that implements the `IUser` interface. If tomorrow I want to change the user class to be used in this context, all I need is a new user class that implements the `IUser` interface.

But in my concrete implementation, in a Symfony controller for example, I'm using an instance of the `UserAdapter` class, which implements the Symfony `UserInterface` interface. When calling the `setUser()` setter on my `Comment` object, the interface doesn't match.

What am I missing?

Am I using the Adapter pattern in a wrong way, should I use a different strategy in my implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solutions that come to my mind. One solution works with inheritance, one with delegation.

1. Inheritance

   In your `UserAdapter` class extend from your DDD `User` class. Also implement the Symfony2 `UserInterface` in the adapter. Now implement the methods from the `UserInterface` by using the attributes from the parent class.
2. Delegation

   Same as in the inheritance case the `UserAdapter` class must implement the Symfony2 `UserInterface`. But now you create an association from the adapter to the concrete user class. So your adapter "has one" user. To avoid having adapters without a user you can require a user in the adapters constructor. Then you can call the setUser method with `setUser($userAdapter->getUser())`.

Comment: I thought of the 2nd solution, which is theoretically nice as it uses composition, but I'm also trying to avoid complexity for the end-developer. By using delegation, I force them to make assumptions on how business objects are composed, unless I develop some other adapter for my `Comment` object which would serve as an intermediate layer to properly set the user.

Using inheritance, if I develop Symfony-like objects, with each one extending their equivalent of the DDD lib, would that be a good solution ? It ensures objects usable in the context of the Symfony app are indeed Symfony compliant.

Comment: Inheritance will only be a problem if you are planning to inherit from another DDD `User` class in the Symfony2 application.